# Many crash reports with android lite sdk from here api last version

Tags: java, android, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

with the new lite android api library I get the following crash report data from Google Play Console on many customers using my application (last library version 4.1.5) :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readByteArray (Parcel.java:2249)
  at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite$SavedState.<init> (Unknown Source:10)
  at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite$SavedState.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite$SavedState$1.createFromParcel (Unknown Source:3)
  at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite$SavedState$1.createFromParcel (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2790)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:2684)
  at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal (Parcel.java:3134)
  at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray (Parcel.java:2367)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:2741)
  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:3053)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked (BaseBundle.java:288)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel (BaseBundle.java:232)
  at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray (Bundle.java:1010)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState (PhoneWindow.java:2182)
  at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState (Activity.java:1195)
  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState (Activity.java:1150)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState (Instrumentation.java:1317)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3153)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:180)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:165)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:142)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:70)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1947)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7037)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Also got this report data :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite.getMapScene (Unknown Source:2)
  at mediacominteractive.com.jelocaliseviewer.ViewMap.CreateMap (ViewMap.java:982)
  at mediacominteractive.com.jelocaliseviewer.ViewMap.lambda$getDataMap$7$ViewMap (ViewMap.java:661)
  at mediacominteractive.com.jelocaliseviewer.-$$Lambda$ViewMap$v0swVppxULx4N4KfETgPrMrUUd8.run (Unknown Source:2)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:888)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:213)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8147)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:513)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Comment: Please provide the code for these stacktraces if you expect help. This is very unspecific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for the community to assist you, please provide a code example that you can use to reproduce this error. Otherwise it will be very hard to diagnose what is wrong. Please check out the guide for how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask